# different generated random numbers on Windows and Linux for a specific PRNG

Tags: r

Running the Mersenne-Twister implementation from the randtoolbox library I get different results

```
library(randtoolbox)
set.generator('MersenneTwister',initialization='init2002',resolution=53,seed=42)
runif(10)
```

Result on Windows:

```
[1] 0.37454012 0.95071431 0.73199394 0.59865848 0.15601864 0.15599452 0.05808361 0.86617615 0.60111501 0.70807258 # Windows
```

Result on Linux:

```
 [1] 0.95071431 0.15599452 0.86617615 0.02058449 0.83244264 0.30424224 0.52475643 0.61185289 0.36636184 0.45606998
```

Why does it happen? Is there a way to get them aligned?

p.s. running from the command line:

```
Rscript -e "library(randtoolbox);set.generator('MersenneTwister',initialization='init2002',resolution=53,seed=42);runif(10)"
```

Comment: Are you sure the version of the packages are the same on both?

Comment: @thc yes, both 1.17.1

Comment: Try Set.seed(1). Are they then the same?

Comment: What about R version?  Random number generation was changed in R 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in randtoolbox: the C code doesn't use width-base integer types like **uint32_t** and has some subtle bugs, when **int** and **long** differ in width (like on Linux 64 bits, but not on Windows). For example in the file `mt19937ar.c` an **int** is assigned to an **unsigned long**, which causes sign extension:

```
static unsigned long mt[N]; /* the array for the state vector  */
...
void putMersenneTwister(int *init, int *res, int *state)
{
...
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        mt[i] = state[i+1];
```

If you replace the last line with:

```
        mt[i] = state[i+1] & 0xffffffffUL;
```

the bug disappears.

Just download the source code, extract it, patch it and execute:

```
R CMD INSTALL randtoolbox
```

in the package parent directory.